# Reflection of a curve around a slant line

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, reflection

a fifth-degree function:

`y = 80*x^5-225*x^4+350*x^3-300*x^2+150*x-20` 
(the green curve in the image)

needs to be reflected/mirrored around the line

`y=55x-20` 
(the blue line)

and I am only interested in the segment [0,1]. While there is plenty of content on the internet on how to reflect around the axes or vertical/horizontal lines, I have not found an algebra explanation of how to do this around a slant line.

[image]

This image is an approximation: the red curve's shape should be slightly different: this is just the difference between the line and the curve, not the reflection.

How do I find the equation of the reflected green curve?

And part 2 of this question: Is it true that applying the equation of the reflection onto the original equation (the green curve) will return the equation of the slant blue line?

so if f*(x) is the reflection: is f*(f(x)) ?= ax+b

A step-by-step explanation would help anyone with a similar problem who sees this post.
There's a similar post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929299/how-to-find-the-equation-of-the-graph-reflected-about-a-line), about reflecting around horizontal/vertical lines.

Thank you!

Comment: By "reflection" do you mean (vertical distance from green to blue) = (vertical distance from blue to red)? [That should be easier] Or do you mean to take a point on the green curve, drop the perpendicular to the blue line (getting a distance $d$) and keep going  the same distance $d$ from there to the other side of the blue line to get a point on the red curve? Your diagram seems like you did the first easier choice.

Comment: I see now that my "diagram" was wrong. By reflection I mean: "take a point on the green curve, drop the perpendicular to the blue line (getting a distance 0 and keep going the same distance  from there to the other side of the blue line to get a point on the red curve"

Comment: Incidentally, a graph of your reflected curve "won't look right" unless the horizontal and vertical scales have the same ratio as the "physical" width-to-height ratio of the plot, i.e., you plot "at true aspect ratio". (The plot in your post is distorted in the vertical direction by a factor of about $100$, in that the piece of plane is about $50$ times taller than it is wide, but your plot is about twice as wide as it is tall.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}$The reflected curve is not generally a graph, but it's easy to obtain a parametric description. For generality, let's say the graph $y = f(x)$ is to be reflected across the line $\ell$ with symmetric equation $ax + by + c = 0$ ($a$ and $b$ not both zero). Dividing the equation of $\ell$ by $\sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}$, we may assume $(a, b)$ is a *unit* vector.

Pick a point $(x_{0}, y_{0})$ on $\ell$, and make a translational change of coordinates so this point is the origin: $(u, v) = (x - x_{0}, y - y_{0})$. The graph becomes $v + y_{0} = f(u + x_{0})$, and the line is $au + bv = 0$.

The (unit) vector $\vec{p} = (-b, a)$ lies on $\ell$, and $\vec{n} = (a, b)$ is orthogonal to $\ell$. Each point $\vec{x} = (u, v)$ is uniquely represented as
\begin{align*}
\vec{x}
  &= (\vec{x} \cdot \vec{p}) \vec{p} + (\vec{x} \cdot \vec{n}) \vec{n} \\
  &= (-bu + av)(-b, a) + (au + bv)(a, b).
\end{align*}
The image of $\vec{x}$ under reflection across $\ell$ is
\begin{align*}
R_{\ell}(\vec{x})
  &= (\vec{x} \cdot \vec{p}) \vec{p} - (\vec{x} \cdot \vec{n}) \vec{n} \\
  &= (-bu + av)(-b, a) - (au + bv)(a, b) \\
  &= \bigl((b^{2} - a^{2})u - 2abv, -2abu - (b^{2} - a^{2})v\bigr).
\tag{1}
\end{align*}
(If we write $(a, b) = (\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$, the coefficients in the preceding expression are $\pm\cos(2\theta)$ and $-\sin(2\theta)$.)

The graph is parametrized by
$$
(u, v) = \bigl(t + x_{0}, f(t + x_{0}) - y_{0}\bigr);
$$
substituting these functions into (1) gives a parametrization of the reflected graph.

Comment: Excellent. The right linear algebra for.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But does the . equal multiply? And why is there in expression (1) a . at the end? It would really help if you could show me a solution with my equations because I'm afraid I'm not mathematically inclined..

Comment: @MisterH: The periods at the end are ordinary punctuation. :) (The other dots are "dot products", but can be ignored if you don't care about deriving or checking the formulas.) It's a little messy to write down a single parametric formula in your situation; if you're working with a CAS, the equations in my answer were selected as "reasonable intermediate steps". In it helps, you have $a = 55/\sqrt{3026}$, $b = -1/\sqrt{3026}$, $x_{0} = 0$, $y_{0} = c = -20/\sqrt{3026}$, $f(x) = $ the fifth-degree polynomial expression in your post. And again, use "true aspect ratio" to get an "accurate" plot.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang You can reflect a function across the line without a parametric description.

Answer (score 3):

In a previous answer in [How do I reflect a function about a specific line?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63973/how-do-i-reflect-a-function-about-a-specific-line) I showed how to derive a formula for $y=f(x)$, if its rotated by $y=mx+b$

Using the formula

$$\left(\frac{2m}{2m^2+1}x'-\frac{1-m^2}{m^2+1}(y'-b)+b\right)=f\left(\frac{2m}{m^2+1}(y'-b)-\frac{1-m^2}{m^2+1}x'\right)$$

If we substitute $f(x)=80x^5-225x^4+350x^3-300x^2+150x-20$, $m=55$ and $b=-20$ you will end up with the following graph. You should get the same picture you found above.

Answer (score 1):

There is equivalent approach if you have a set $ { \left\{ \left( {x}_{i}, {y}_{i} \right) \right\} }_{i = 1}^{n} $.
Given a slant line with angle of $ \theta $ form the origin you can do the following steps:

1. Rotate the vectors by $ \theta $ clock wise using a [Rotation Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).
2. Reflect the results over the $ y = 0 $ line by negating the $ y $ coordinate.
3. Rotate the data back using the inverse of the Rotation Matrix.

All that can be integrated into one matrix where the steps above are just its [Eigen Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix).
This is for finite set of points.
Actually for a function, it is the same if you write it a parameterized manner of a vector.

Funny thing happens if you chose the line to be $ g \left( x \right) = x $.
To reflect a function $ y = f \left( x \right) $ over $ g \left( x \right) $ let's right it as $ \left( y, f \left( x \right) \right) $.
Now the reflection is given by $ \left( f \left( x \right), y \right) $.

Why is that?

To rotate by 45 degrees a point given by $ \left(x, y \right) $ let's write it in the complex plane form - $ x + iy $.
To rotate a complex point by 45 Degrees clock one should multiply it by $ \frac{1 - i}{\sqrt{2}} $.
The coordinates of the new point are given by $ \frac{x + y}{\sqrt{2}} + i \frac{y - x}{\sqrt{2}} \rightarrow \left( \frac{x + y}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{y - x}{\sqrt{2}} \right) $

Now, reflect it over the y axis by negating the second element which yields $ \left( \frac{x + y}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{x - y}{\sqrt{2}} \right) $.

Now rotate back this by multiplying by $ 1 + i $ which yields $ y + ix $ namely the new coordinates are $ \left( y, x \right) $.

Enjoy...