# Drawing the image of a circle under reflection through its center?

Tags: geometry, isometry

Would the image of a circle of radius r, center P under a reflection through its center remain in the same position? I am guessing that it is, but unfortunately I've found no other sources that verify this answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is... you can proof this using coordinate geometry

Comment: Yes. it would be. Remember that any line through the circle's centre is the diameter and it splits the circle into two semicircles, say $A$ and $B$. Reflecting in the diameter reflects $A$ onto $B$ and $B$ onto $A$. Thereby the circle remains the same.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1693953/if-the-reflection-of-the-hyperbola-xy-4-in-the-line-x-y-1-0-is-xy

Answer (score 0):

The geometry stays the same,that is we still see the same graph.

The points on the circle  move around such that their images under the reflection form the same circle.